# In python replacing characters from multiple char maps

Tags: python, encode, codec

I haven't been able to find a solution to this problem, and it's for a workaround in some bad platform code that I can't do anything about. I want to render UTF-8 strings but the platform crashes if it receives a character out side it's supported character maps. In the case here, I have German Navi unit in Russia - Latin 2 (iso-8859-2) and Cyrillic (iso-8859-5) are supported but the platform crashes on an Arabic character. So I want to filter out anything that is not German or Russian.

This code:

```
import codecs
import string

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = u'Ivan Krsti\u0107\u0416'

    print s

    print s.encode ('iso-8859-1', 'replace')
    print s.encode ('iso-8859-5', 'replace').decode('iso-8859-5')
    print s.encode ('iso-8859-2', 'replace').decode('iso-8859-2')
```

Produces

```
Ivan KrstićЖ 
Ivan Krsti??
Ivan Krsti?Ж
Ivan Krstić?
```

My question is how to I combine the character maps for 'iso-8859-2' and 'iso-8859-5' so I get the first result after filtering? (Assume that I've already encoded UTF-8 to unicode.)

Comment: So you want to only include codepoints that are valid in either ISO-8859-5 or ISO-8859-2?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I know it's kind of odd.

Comment: So what should happen with text that can only be displayed in one or the other, but not in both?

Comment: The rendering software works with the combined set. It's the Chinese, Arabic, etc. that makes it come apart. I will extend your solution to include all supported languages on the platform, which is all of Europe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can produce all codepoints that are valid for either codec using sets:

```
iso_8859_2 = {chr(i).decode('iso-8859-2') for i in xrange(0xff)}
iso_8859_5 = {chr(i).decode('iso-8859-5') for i in xrange(0xff)}
combined = iso_8859_2 | iso_8859_5
```

and then make that into a regular expression:

```
import re
# escape meta characters
invalid = u''.join(combined).replace('-', r'\-').replace(']', r'\]')
invalid = re.compile(u'([^{}])'.format(invalid))
```

and apply that to Unicode text to filter out all codepoints that fall outside those codepoints:

```
text_using_only_iso_8859_2_or_5 = invalid.sub('', unicodetext)
```

This then removes any codepoints that are *not* in either of the given character sets.

You could also work with `unicode.translate()`, which takes a mapping of codepoints (integers) to new codepoints, or `None`to remove characters:

```
all_of_unicode = set(range(0x10ffff))
iso_8859_2 = {ord(chr(i).decode('iso-8859-2')) for i in xrange(0xff)}
iso_8859_5 = {ord(chr(i).decode('iso-8859-5')) for i in xrange(0xff)}
# map the difference to None values
to_remove = dict.fromkeys(all_of_unicode - iso_8859_2 - iso_8859_5)
text_using_only_iso_8859_2_or_5 = unicodetext.translate(to_remove)
```

Comment: Martijn you are the bomb! This totally works. Thanks for lending a helping hand.

Comment: @DaveFugelso: since you are going to remove more sets, I gave you another solution that may be faster, depending on the size of the set. Use the `timeit` module to see what works better for your specific combinations of text and character sets to retain.

Comment: @MartijnPieters.I added iso-8859-7 and iso-8859-9 and tested against a longer test string with unallowed characters. Timing came in at .25 sec and .32 sec solution respectively solution 1 and 2 for 100000 runs. The regular expression solution appears to be slightly faster. (This was on test_string not creating the char maps.) That was on my laptop - need to run it on the platform.

Comment: @DaveFugelso: I guess that is expected; there is a lot of overlap between the ISO-8859 codecs and they only touch a small portion of Unicode, so the regex will still remain a smaller set than the translation map in that case.